# Adding all the rows of an array after formating Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I add up all the elements of each row of a multidimensional numpy array. I am trying to turn the '--' elements to `0` and then adding all the rows right after. How could I do such a thing? The `--` elements of the result of the masked array.

```
Array = np.array([[--, --, --, --, --, --, --]
 [3, 4, --, --, --, --, --]
 [--, --, 5, 7, 8, 10, --]
 [--, --, --, --, --, --, --]
 [--, --, --, --, --, --, 20]])
np.where(Array != "--", result, 0)
Array.sum(axis=0)
```

Expected Output:

```
[0 7 30 0 20]
```

Comment: Are the --s supposed to be surrounded with quotes? `"--"`

Comment: It was actually after formatting an array it gives out -- for the empty spaces in the `Array`.

Comment: `Array = np.array([[--, --, --, --, --, --, --]
 [3, 4, --, --, --, --, --]
 [--, --, 5, 7, 8, 10, --]
 [--, --, --, --, --, --, --]
 [--, --, --, --, --, --, 20]])` should throw an error.

Comment: Is this a masked array or a mixed of string and numbers array (which is an object array)? It would help if you provide how you get this array. Thank you

Comment: @QWERTYL ye like Ehsan said said it is a masked array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.ma.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 5, 7, 8, 10, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20]
    ],
    mask=[
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    ]
)

array = array.filled(0)
print(np.sum(array, axis=1))
```

Alternatively, if you want to apply the sum on the masked array before filling with zeros:

```py
array.fill_value = 0
print(np.ma.sum(array, axis=1).filled(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
>>> np.where(arr == '--', 0, arr).astype(int).sum(1)
array([ 0,  7, 30,  0, 20])
```

Comment: This does not work since the `--` elements are that of a masked array, sorry updated the issue.